# Can we say $|xy^iz| = a^{p+i|y|}b^p$?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

Using the Pumping-Lemma for $ \{L = a^nb^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} $.

We define $p \in \mathbb{N}$ 
It exists a word $w = a^pb^p$ 
For every $|w| \ge p$: $w=xyz$, $y > 0$, $|xy| \le p$ 
Because of $|xy| \le p$, we can say that y only consists of a's or b's. 
For the language to be regular $|xy^iz| \in L$ 
Which means $|xy^iz| = a^{p+i|y|}b^p$ or $|xy^iz| = a^pb^{p+i|y|}$

My question is, is the expression $|xy^iz| = a^{p+i|y|}b^p$ correct? \

Lets fill $i=3$ would mean $|xy^3z| = a^{p+|y|+|y|+|y|}b^p$

Comment: Please edit the question's body to get an actual question there.

Comment: Done @BaderAbuRadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you suggested does not work. As a sanity check, consider pumping down with $i = 0$ -- this should result in a word with a fewer number of a's.

If you consider the word $w = a^p b^p$, where $p > 0$ is a pumping constant, then since $w\in L$ and $|w| \geq p$, we can parition $w = xyz$ where:

1- $|xy| \leq p$

2- $y\neq \epsilon$

3- $\forall i\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0\}$, it holds that $xy^iz\in L$

Now by items 1 and 2,  we can write $x = a^l, y = a^m, $ and $z = a^n\cdot b^p$, where $l+m \leq p, m\neq 0, l+m+n = p$, and $l, m, n \geq 0$. Using item 3, we get that for all $i\geq 0$, $$xy^iz = a^l a^{im} a^{n}b^p =  a^{l+m+n + (i-1)m}b^p = a^{p + (i-1)m} b^p = a^{p + (i-1)|y|} b^p \in L$$

So by pumping $i$ times the word $y$, we get the word $a^{p + (i-1)|y|} b^p$, and not  $a^{p + i|y|} b^p$.

Comment: Makes sense. $|ay^1z|$ does not equal $a^{p+|y|}$. $|ay^2z|$ does.